# Printing selected charts

Tags: javascript, printing, charts, fusioncharts

I am using Fusioncharts in multiple divs and i want to make it possible for my users to be able to select the charts they want and then print the selected ones can anyone help me whith this?

Comment: Look at this [article](http://kb.fusioncharts.com/questions/385/__print). Though it is old, this might give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts offers API for printing the charts. Please visit the [API Documentation](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html#print).

So say you have 6 charts in your beautiful dashboard and you have 6 checkboxes for each. Bind each one of them pointing to a chart Instance, checking which, calls the API for the chart instance to print itself.

Let me know if you still have a concern.